# How to persist a very abstract data type between sessions

Tags: php, session, persist, abstract-data-type

I have an abstract data type that behaves much like stack.  It represents a history of "graph objects" made by a particular user.

Each "graph object" holds one or more "lines", a date range, keys, and a title.

Each "line" holds a sql generator configured for a particular subset of data in my db.

I would like for these "histories" to be available to users between their sessions.  It will be in the form of a tab that reads something like "most recent graphs".

What do you believe to be the best way to persist this type of data between sessions.  This application could get rather large, so efficiency is a concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you had a look at serialize:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

You could use this in conjunction with a database.